# Getting started with the FacebookSDK.framework

Tags: ios, facebook, ios7

I am having trouble using the FacebookSDK.framework.

My iOS app needs to post some simple message on FB.

If the user is logged in at the device setting level, it all works fine using:

```
SLComposeViewController *facebkController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
```

… and so on.

If this is not the case, I try to rely on the FacebookSDK.framework, but I am having problems.

I followed the steps described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/
and then tried the HelloFacebookSample example program. This all worked fine.

After that I got into the task of integrating the FacebookSDK.framework into my own app. This is where things go wrong.
I have created a new app on: https://developers.facebook.com/
and then intended to follow the steps in the getting-started document mentioned above, while trying to mimic what I can see in the HelloFacebookSample.
But I must be missing some important details, because nothing is posted.

What am I (probably) doing wrong?

Bye.

P.S. In case that helps I include below the method fired when I push the FB button in my app:

```
- (IBAction)faceBkButtonHandler:(id)sender
{
        NSURL *urlToShare = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://developers.facebook.com/ios"];

        // If it is available, we will first try to post using the share dialog in the Facebook app
        FBAppCall *appCall = [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:urlToShare
                                                              name:@"Hello Facebook"
                                                           caption:nil
                                                       description:@"The 'Hello Facebook' sample application showcases simple Facebook integration."
                                                           picture:nil
                                                       clientState:nil
                                                           handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                                               if (error) {
                                                                   NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
                                                               } else {
                                                                   NSLog(@"Success!");
                                                               }
                                                           }];

        if (!appCall) {
            // Next try to post using Facebook's iOS6 integration
            BOOL displayedNativeDialog = [FBDialogs presentOSIntegratedShareDialogModallyFrom:self
                                                                                  initialText:nil
                                                                                        image:nil
                                                                                          url:urlToShare
                                                                                      handler:nil];

            if (!displayedNativeDialog) {
                // Lastly, fall back on a request for permissions and a direct post using the Graph API
                [self performPublishAction:^{
                    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HERE (22) at %@",[NSDate date]];

                    FBRequestConnection *connection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];

                    connection.errorBehavior = FBRequestConnectionErrorBehaviorReconnectSession
                    | FBRequestConnectionErrorBehaviorAlertUser
                    | FBRequestConnectionErrorBehaviorRetry;

                    [connection addRequest:[FBRequest requestForPostStatusUpdate:message]
                         completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

                             //[self showAlert:message result:result error:error];
                             //self.buttonPostStatus.enabled = YES;
                         }];
                    [connection start];

                    //self.buttonPostStatus.enabled = NO;
                }];
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're (probably) doing wrong without seeing your code.

Comment: OK. I have modified my post to include the main method concerned.
Let me know if more is needed, since I may do some wrong settings somewhere else. This code has been mostly taken from some sample and I am trying to make it work.
It seems like appCall is never nil, so the the problem must be in the first part.